# Type switcher based on enum C++

Tags: c++, templates, enums, switch-statement

all!

I want write a template structure, which will give me concrete name of a class based on enum. In details:

in .h file

```
#include "Mish.h"
#include "ReLU.h"

namespace a
{

namespace b
{

enum class ActivationEnum : size_t
{
    Mish,
    ReLU
};

template <ActivationEnum act>
struct Activation
{
};

template <>
struct Activation<ActivationEnum::Mish>
{
    using aType = Mish;
};

template <>
struct Activation<ActivationEnum::ReLU>
{
    using aType = ReLU;
};

} // raul namespace

}
```

Then I want to use it in code as:

```
void someF(..., ActivationEnum act)
{
...
    OtherClass<Activation<act>::aType> bla;
...
}
```

I've faced with two problems:

1. Mish and ReLU are implemented in Mish.cpp and ReLU.cpp files in `namespace a`, includes are here, but I got errors `syntax error: identifier 'ReLU'` and syntax `error: identifier 'Mish'`. If I add forward declaration here such as `namespace a { class Mish; class ReLU; ... }` then everything is ok here.
2. No matter in function someF I receive invalid template argument for `'a::b::Activation', expected compile-time constant expression`
   What are the problems? How can I return different typenames based on enum? Thank you.

Comment: `using aType = Mish;` would require `Mish` to be a type. But it's not a type, it's the value of an `enum`. You could instead use `static constexpr ActivationEnum aValue = Mish;`

Comment: You can't use runtime values as template arguments. You have to rethink how to write this.

Comment: put "Factory method pattern" in your favorite search engine